# In swift, when one property has no default value, the default values held by other properties become useless?

Tags: ios, swift

In swift, I have the following code:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var nose: Int = 1
}

var mike = Person(name: "mike", nose: 1)
var john = Person(name: "john") //error: missing argument for parameter 'nose' in call
```

Although nose has a default value, I have to specify a value for it. My question is, does default value of nose become totally useless and I can simply write the declaration as the following?

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var nose: Int
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *The Swift Programming Language*

> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they
>   do not define any of their own custom initializers. This is true even
>   if the structure’s stored properties do not have default values.
>
> The memberwise initializer is a shorthand way to initialize the member
>   properties of new structure instances. Initial values for the
>   properties of the new instance can be passed to the memberwise
>   initializer by name.

As you haven't declared any initialisers for your struct, the only initialiser that is available is the memberwise initialiser.

You can declare an initialiser that just takes a name in order to use the default value for `nose`.  This then requires you to explicitly declare the memberwise initialiser -

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var nose: Int = 1

    init(_ name:String) {
        self.name=name;
    }

    init (name:String, nose:Int){
        self.name=name;
        self.nose=nose;
    }
}


var mike = Person(name: "mike", nose: 1)
var john = Person("john")
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this form because it is so flexible:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var nose: Int

    init(name: String = "Anon", nose: Int = 1) {
        self.name=name;
        self.nose=nose;
    }
}


var sally = Person(nose: 2, name: "Sally")
var anon1 = Person(nose: 1)
var anon2 = Person()
var mike = Person(name: "mike", nose: 1)
var john = Person(name: "john")
```

Note 5 different initialiser combinations possible. Essentially it allows you to treat Person like a person builder (Builder pattern).